# Export the azimuthal coordinates of a star between a range of dates

Tags: software-rec, calculator

Is there a program to export the azimuthal coordinates of a cellestial object (HIP54255) *(that is, where do I see the object in the earth's sky, at a specific location?)* between a range of dates, for a specific location, each minute or so ?

That is:

Input:

- Galactic or equatorial coordinates of the cellestial object,
- Location (latitude, longitude) on where I want to see the object
- Range of dates

Output:

- File containing the coordinates by minute (or so), between the range of dates

Comment: Not precisely what you're asking for, but a [Wolfram Alpha query](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=position+of+HIP54255+from+los+angeles+on+december+21+at+4:34+am) might be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think [Astronomical Almanac](http://www.moshier.net/) (`aa-56.zip` on that page, [`astronomical-almanac`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/astronomical-almanac) [image: Install astronomical-almanac] in Ubuntu and others) can do these calculations. I don't know if you can get your desired input and output formats without serious pre- and post-processing.